# which cryptographic algorithm can encrypt and decrypt blocks for 512bytes?

Tags: cryptography, arm, stm32

im looking for the crypto algorithm that can encrypt and decrypt blocks for 512bytes, the whole file will be 1mb size, and crypted will be trasfered to stm32 mcu, then in stm32 it will be decrypted for next procedure. Which algorithm i can use?

Comment: Why does it have to be 512 bytes? A block cipher with a block size that's any smaller power of 2, like AES, can always be used multiple times to pretend it's a block cipher of 512. Do you want some mathematical or security property unique to 512 byte block ciphers?

Comment: The [Hasty Pudding cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasty_Pudding_cipher) allows 512 bit blocks, though it is not as commonly implemented as AES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least one block cipher that is [Threefish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threefish) that supports 256, 512, and 1024 block sizes with equal size keys, respectively. 512 block size needs 72 rounds to be secure. Whereas AES with a 128-bit block size needs 14 rounds for a 256-bit key, and a 256-bit key is the golden standard that is even secure against quantum adversaries.

With CTR mode, you can call AES 4 times under the same key to encrypt your message faster than Threefish if we assume they have similar round performance - only needs 56 round calculations.

One can prefer AES-256 since it is extensively analyzed and resisted attacks for more than 20 years.